# DotPulsar :How to set consumer receiveQueue Size?

Tags: c#, sdk, message, .net-5, apache-pulsar

Pulsar .Net SDK -DotPulsar How to set consumer receiveQueue Size?
await using var consumer = client1.NewConsumer(Schema.String)
.StateChangedHandler(Monitor)
.ConsumerName(consurName)
.SubscriptionName("Forward-Sub3")
.SubscriptionType(SubscriptionType.Shared)
.Topic(myTopic)
.Create();

```
        Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl+C to exit");

        await ConsumeMessages(consumer, cts.Token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the 'MessagePrefetchCount' ("Number of messages that will be prefetched. The default is 1000") on the IConsumerBuilder and IReaderBuilder.

Best regards
db